# Django. Simple Celery task not working

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I'm new to `Celery`. I have a task that is not working adn I don't know why. Im using `rabbitmq` Here is my code:

In settings.py:

```
BROKER_URL = "amqp://guest@localhost//"
```

tasks.py:

```
from celery.decorators import task
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
from hisoka.models import FeralSpirit, Fireball

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@task
def test_task():
    fireball = Fireball.objects.last()
    feral_spirit = FeralSpirit.objects.filter(fireball=fireball).last()

    counters = feral_spirit.increase_counter()

    logger.info(feral_spirit + "counters: " + counters)
```

The task is just a test, it is designed to increase a counter that is a field of the FeralSpirit model. It works correctly if I don't call the function with `delay()`

views.py

```
class FireballDetail(ListView):

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        test_task.delay()

        ...
```

I have a `rabbitmq` server running correctly (or at least it looks like that) on one terminal and the django localhost server on another terminal. Am I missing something obvious? I have a `celery.py` and a modified `__init__` file, exactly following the [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html).

Comment: when you said "django localhost server", did you mean your celery worker? Check if you have your celery worker running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your celery worker is not running, try

```
celery  -A {project_name} worker --loglevel=info -Q {queue_name}
```

Substitute the value of project_name and queue_name. Default queue_name is `default`

Comment: Thanks for you answer man, I couldn't test it today. I'll do it tommorrow.

Comment: Hey man. you where right, my celery worker wasn't running. But now it is running and it still doesn't work. Just edited the question to add that info.